# Livewire if parameter not on database go to error 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

How do I handle my routes or component controller when a route parameter is not found in the database, instead of showing the error exception page I want it to be re-routed or shows a different page of "Error 404 Slug not Valid" or something

```
Route::get('/{slug}', Main::class)->missing(function () {return view('welcome');});
```

I tried this but didn't not change anything.
I'm using laravel 8 and livewire

Comment: you can use `abort(404,"Error 404 Slug not Valid")` not route model binding

Comment: Sample code? Don't know how to implement directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fallback route to do this trick. Your code will be like this

```
Route::fallback( function() { return view('custom-not-found-blade'); } )
```

Every time the route is not found it will redirect you to **custom-not-found-blade**  view.

You can read more about fallback routes in laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes

Comment: This doesn't work because the route is found because it is a dynamic route, means anything can enter but would like it to redirect to error 404 when  the parameter founds nothing in the database.

Comment: Have you tired it?

Comment: Yes,  I already tried putting it on the top of web.php and  at the bottom of web.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your controller like this:

```
$item = YourModel::where('slug',$slug)->get();
  if($item->count() > 0){
   return view('your-view' , compact('item'));
  }else{
   return view('404-view');
  }
```